# Loop error in Javascript: code ignores conditionals

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I was creating a prime number identifier. However, regardless of the number I put it identifies as a prime. I don't know what is wrong in the code.

```
let primo = (number) => {
    const numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    for(n = 2; n < number; n++) {
    if(number % n === 0) {
    resultado.textContent = 'Esse número não é primo.'; // "This number is not prime"
    } }  
    resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.'; // "This number is prime"
}

 
calcular.addEventListener('click', primo);
```

```
<div class="input">
                <label>Número:</label>
                <input type="number" id='numero'>

                <button id='calcular'>É primo?</button>

                <div class="result" id='resultado'></div>

            </div>
```

Comment: `resultado.textContent` can only contain one value. So it will always be the last one checked

Comment: The last statement that executes is `resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.';`, after the `for` loop. It should `return` as soon as the number has been detected to not be prime.

Comment: Other than what @axiac and @Liam have indicated, it is also notable that one may not necessarily loop from 2 to 'number' to test if 'number' is prime. It may be sufficient to loop from 2 to 'number / 2' (or `Math.ceil(number/2)`).

Comment: @jsN00b I don't know why people think that checking from `2` to `number/2` improves the solution (but I've seen and heard this suggestion too many times to remember). It is still [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). If you want to improve the loop then you run it until `sqrt(number)`. For `n === 1_000_000`, the original code runs the loop for 1,000,000 times, `number/2` makes it run for 500,000 times (not a big improvement) and `sqrt(number)` makes it run for 1000 times.

Comment: @jsN00b Why appologize? Your suggestion to improve the speed of the code by reducing the number of iterations is good. It just can be improved by using `sqrt(number)`. It can be improved even more by using a precomputed table of prime number but this is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @axiac, sorry I deleted my comment from earlier. It posted too soon and only the initial couple words were shown. In any case, it did not add value & hence I saw it fit to be removed. The `number / 2`, was 'sufficient' in comparison to looping all the way. Obviously, `sqrt(number)` is even better - hands-down.

Answer (score 4):

Let's indent the code properly:

```js
let primo = (number) => {
    const numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    for (n = 2; n < number; n++) {
      if (number % n === 0) {
        resultado.textContent = 'Esse número não é primo.'; // "This number is not prime"
      }
    } 
    resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.'; // "This number is prime"
}
```

I hope that it is clear for you that, no matter the value of `number`, the last statement that executes is `resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.'` (after the loop ends).
It sets the value that you see in the page and overwrites any value that could have been set there during the loop.

In order to fix the error the function must return as soon as the number has been detected to be non-prime (inside the `if` block).

Another problem in the code is that the function expects an argument (`number`) but it is called with an argument that is not what it expects (the event). The function also gets a value from the form (`numero`) but it ignores it. Given the way you install it as an event handler and the rest of its code I think it should use the value of `numero` instead of `number`.

```js
let primo = () => {
    const number = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    for (n = 2; n < number; n++) {
      if (number % n === 0) {
        resultado.textContent = 'Esse número não é primo.'; // "This number is not prime";
        return;
      }
    } 
    resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.'; // "This number is prime"
}
```

---

There are further improvements that you can apply to your code.

First of all, decouple the logic from the UI. Instead of manipulating the document from the function let the function do only the computation and move the code that works with the document in a separate function:

```js
function primo(number) {
  for (let n = 2; n < number; n++) {
    if (number % n === 0) {
      return false;          // not prime
    }
  }

  return true;               // prime
}


function checkIfPrime() {
  // Get the value to check; expect the string to be a number represented in base 10
  const numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value, 10);
  const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

  // Check if the number is prime and prepare the message accordingly
  let message; 
  if (prime(numero)) {
    message = 'Esse número é primo.';
  } else {
    message = 'Esse número não é primo.';
  }

  // Put the message on screen
  resultado.textContent = message;
}

calcular.addEventListener('click', checkIfPrime);
```

This way the function `primo()` can be reused in other pages or in other contexts (where a form is not present).

Then, as @jsnoob suggests in a comment, there is no need to check all the values to `number` but you can stop earlier. Not on `number/2` but on `sqrt(number)`. And this makes the code run much faster for big values of `number`:

```js
function primo(number) {
  for (let n = 2; n <= Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)); n++) {
    if (number % n === 0) {
      return false;          // not prime
    }
  }

  return true;               // prime
}
```

Read about [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and [`Math.sqrt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt).

Another improvement, as suggested by @teabx, is to validate the value of `number` against negative numbers. It should also be validated for non-integer values (the prime numbers are always positive integer numbers).

```js
function primo(number) {
  // the numbers smaller than or equal to 1 are not primes
  if (number <= 1) {
    return false;
  }

  // only the integral numbers can be prime
  if (Math.floor(number) !== number) {
    return false;              // not integer
  }

  // divide to each integer number between 2 and its square root
  // there is no need to divide it by greater values; if the number
  // has a factor greater than its square root, then the other factor
  // is smaller that the square root
  for (let n = 2; n <= Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)); n++) {
    if (number % n === 0) {
      return false;          // not prime
    }
  }

  return true;               // prime
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! It works!!!!!!

Comment: One small thing to note is that this solution incorrectly identifies numbers <1 (including negatives) as prime numbers. You would have to add some sort of input validation to return false if the supplied number is <1

Comment: @Teabx You are right.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The top answer updated their solution, so this is no longer valid.

Okay, the answer posted already is correct, but there is another problem with your code. The problem is with the variable you are using on the "**for**" loop.

The **number** variable that is passed to the function primo, is going to be of type **PointerEvent** because the function is being used as an event handler.

Change all instances of "number" to "numero" inside the function, and it should work fine:

```
let primo = (number) => {
    const numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    for (n = 2; n < numero; n++) {
        if (numero % n === 0) {
            resultado.textContent = 'Esse número não é primo.'; // "This number is not prime";
            return;
        }
    } 
    resultado.textContent = 'Esse número é primo.'; // "This number is prime"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct code would be:

```
let primo = (number) => {
const numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
let prime = true;
for(n = 2; n < number && prime; n++) {
    if(number % n === 0) {
    prime = false;          
    } 
} 

resultado.textContent = prime ? 'Esse número é primo.' : 'Esse número não é primo.';
```

}